# Choosing suits of cards in a row

Tags: probability, fractions

Three cards from a standard deck are dealt. What is the probability that the first is a heart, the second is a spade, and the third is another heart?

I have figured out so far that you can use casework, and the cases could be HSH, HHS, or SHH. So you should figure out the probability for each, which ends up as

HSH: 1/4 X 13/51 x 12/50 = 13/850

HHS: 1/4 x 12/51 x 13/50 = 13/850

SHH: 1/4 X 13/51 X 12/51 = 13/850

So 13 + 13 + 13 / 850 right?

I need verification if someone can tell me if I'm doing this problem right.

Comment: Order matters, so it is only HSH.  Less work!

Comment: You have calculated the probability that two of the cards are hearts and the other is a spade. But the problem says that frist and third are hearts and the second is a spade, so the answer is the probability of HSH.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Is there a way to close my question? I'm new to Stack Exhange.

Answer (score 0):

The odds of the 1st card being a heart is 1/4. For the 2nd card,the odds of getting one of 13 spades from 51 cards is 13/51. For the 3rd card the odds of getting one of the remaining 12 spades from 50 cards is 12/50. The product of these 3 odds is 13/850, the answer.